# Removing/Replacing &#x201D; from string

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode numeric HTML entities in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764781/how-to-decode-numeric-html-entities-in-php)

How does one remove/replace `&#x201D;` characters from a string?

I've tried `html_entity_decode` but it don't seem to work. There are other similar characters in the string that don't seem to be converted or removed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `html_entity_decode()` doesn't translate numeric entities.

I added an answer to the suggested duplicate [How to decode numeric HTML entities in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764781/how-to-decode-numeric-html-entities-in-php/6243331#6243331)

Answer (score 1):

```
str_replace(array('”', '&#x201D;'), '', $thestring);
```

Here is a working example: http://codepad.org/gXrZcxaF

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you're looking for:

- http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php Converting smart quotes and other characters with PHP so they display correctly
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#84612 Dealing with Numeric entities in PHP (comment on the manual)

Comment: Please [provide context for links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Summarize the information in your answer, preferably including a code snippet.

Comment: as @Gilles correctly pointed out, you need to provide context for links and a ideally a summary and code example. As it stands you're asking the user if this is going to be a solution rather than asserting that it is the solution which verges on "Not an answer". Thanks.

Comment: Prior to editing of the question, the question was unclear, so all I had was shots in the dark (of which I think both were decent). I'm not going to copy/paste an answer from another site into Stack Overflow, the site is a link black hole as it is, I'm not going to resort to plagiarism.