# How to convert code hex to associated character in php

Tags: php

I need to convert code hex such as

```
&#x201D;
```

to its associated character, which is

```
”
```

using php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to decode numeric HTML entities in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764781/how-to-decode-numeric-html-entities-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764781/how-to-decode-numeric-html-entities-in-php

Comment: You could use something like html_entity_decode

Comment: Pls accept the correct ans so that this discussion can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to use ENT_QUOTES parameter in html_entity_decode. This will convert both double and single quotes. Without it the quotes aren't converted. Coincidentally the character is a double quote.

So use:

```
html_entity_decode ($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

if you are trying to convert double quotes or characters such as these:

```
&#x201C;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try-

```
$string = "&#x201D;"; 

echo html_entity_decode ($string );
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/127806)

Answer (score 0):

Try [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)("&#x201D;").

Answer (score 0):

You can use this preg_replace to make a normal character

```
preg_replace('/\\\\x([0-9a-f]{2})/e', 'chr(hexdec($1))', '&#x201D;');
```