# How to decode &#39 in php

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding

I am using an api that returns string that include encodings like this:

```
"It&#39;s a bit of a slow week"
```

I want this to be decoded into a human readable format using php.

I've tried `html_entity_decode`, `rawurldecode`, and `quoted_printable_decode`. I've even checked stackoverflow questions and tried more involved strategies including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764781/how-to-decode-numeric-html-entities-in-php) to no avail (it uses deprecated syntax anyway, and I wouldn't have liked keeping it in my application).

So does anyone know what type of encoding this is, and how to decode it in php?

Comment: `html_entity_decode()` works. See [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mvx9-du9b)

Comment: @HoboSapiens if you view the source, it's still encoded. It's just the browser rendering it like that

Comment: If you display it in a browser with charset=utf-8 it will be human readable.

Comment: @rjdown Noted. Add the `ENT_QUOTES` flag. See my answer.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`html_entity_decode()` ignores quotes by default, but will do what you want if you add the `ENT_QUOTES` flag:

```
<?php
    $a = "It&#39;s working fine.";
    $b = html_entity_decode($a, ENT_QUOTES);
    var_dump($b); // string(18) "It's working fine." 
?>
```

[Fiddle here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5v27-fzzh)

[PHP Reference](http://php.net/html_entity_decode)

Comment: Thank you! It works and I learned a little more about `html_entity_decode`! Exactly everything you can hope for from a stackoverflow question

Comment: Thank you! Like 

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the comments here http://php.net/html_entity_decode#104617

> If you need something that converts &#[0-9]+ entities to UTF-8, this
>   is simple and works:

```
<?php
$input = "Fovi&#269;";

$output = preg_replace_callback("/(&#[0-9]+;)/", function($m) { return mb_convert_encoding($m[1], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES"); }, $input);

/* Plain UTF-8. */
echo $output;
?>
```

Seems to work well.